# php randomly select records from database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

I have a table with over 300,000 records. I need to select 10 or 13 or 20 records from this table.

I have tried following ways.

This takes long time to select

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,12
```

OR

This way same thing but i can't seem to select more then 1 record

```
$temp = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM products limit 0,12');
if ( count( $temp ) > 0 ) {
    $j = 1;
    foreach( $temp as $index => $row ) {
        $p[$j++] = $row[id];
    }
    $my_p= $p[ rand( 1, --$j ) ];
    $pp = 'SELECT id FROM products WHERE id = {$my_p}';
}
```

UPDATE:
Following this [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

I have

```
    SELECT * FROM QM_Products AS r1 
JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM QM_Products )) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This works Thank you all.

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: My problem is that how can I make it run faster.

Comment: Look at the sidebar. Multiple questions about the same issue.

Comment: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: I need to select more then one record. How can i do this

Comment: SELECT `field` FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose to use this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM QM_Products AS r1 
JOIN (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM QM_Products )) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

However, I will point out that you could get fewer than 10 rows, if the random expression returns an id close to the end of the table.

Also, this isn't much of a random selection, because the rows returned will always have adjacent id values.

Aside from the `ORDER BY RAND()` solution (of course this doesn't perform well on large datasets because it can't use an index), I can think of another way to select a number of rows randomly.  Here's some pseudo-PHP code:

```
// MAX(id) is quicker than COUNT(*) in InnoDB
$maxid = query "SELECT MAX(id) FROM QM_Products"

// generate a list of N random values, making sure they're distinct
$id_list = array();
while (count($idlist) < 10) {
  $rand_id = mt_rand(1,$maxid);
  $id_list[$rand_id] = 1;
}

// convert the id list to a comma-separated string in an SQL query
$id_list = implode(",", array_keys($id_list)); 
$rows = query "SELECT * FROM QM_Products WHERE id IN ($id_list)"
```

You might get fewer than N rows if the random values hit gaps where no row exists with a matching id.  But the above method is much faster than `ORDER BY RAND()` or issuing N queries for 1 row at a time.  So you could design a loop to repeat the search as many times as necessary to find N rows.  This wouldn't be good if you have very large gaps, because it could loop for a long time before finding enough rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this php Code

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM user");  
$d = mysql_fetch_row($r);  
$rand = mt_rand(0,$d[0] - 1);  

$r = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user LIMIT $rand, 1");
```

Comment: I'm getting same records.